# Подключение DLL расположенную на сервере в свою программу C#

Tags: c#, dll

Возникла потребность вынести часть кода на сервер в виде библиотеки DLL. Задача скачать DLL в память, и из памяти использовать методы DLL.
По своей задаче нашёл один ответ, но как вызвать свой метод мне не понятно.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] assemblyBytes = webClient.DownloadData("https://mysite.com");
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
var types = assembly.DefinedTypes;
```

Как вызвать методы DLL скачанной в память ?
К примеру DLL написан на C# и имеет такою структуру.

```
class myClass
{
    public static int GetSum(int arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    public static int GetNum(int arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    public static int GetId(int arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Можешь немного конкретнее описать суть проблемы. Есть ли у тебя информация об этой dll ми на чём написана сама dll и всё подобное.

Comment: @Kamushek добавил пример структуры DLL

Comment: @DigitalCore, слушаюсь! :) спич о том как подключить длл, можно через маршалинг, но у вас свое видение решений. В моем ответе рассматривался иной способ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пример вызова статического метода:

```
var type = assembly.GetType("Namespace.TypeName");
var method = type.GetMethod("StaticMethod");
var result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { param1, param2 });
```

Но лучше всего будет задать некий интерфейс/базовый класс в вашей программе, а класс в скачиваемой длл должен реализовать интерфейс/наследовать класс. Например вот так:

```
// интерфейс в вашей программе
public interface IRemote
{
    int DoSomething(string param1, int param2);
}

// его реализация в скачиваемой длл, она должна иметь референс на вашу программу
public class RemoteClass : IRemote
{
    public int DoSomething(string param1, int param2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(param1);
    }
}
```

И дальше вы делаете так:

```
var type = assembly.GetType("Namespace.RemoteClass");
var remote = (IRemote)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
remote.DoSomething("qwerty", 100);
```

Преимущества этого подхода в том, что вам не нужно каждый метод получать при помощи `GetMethod`, и исключаются ошибки, когда передаются неправильные параметры при вызове `MethodInfo.Invoke`.

Comment: Ответы всех пользователей верны, для моих задач подошёл идеально этот.

Answer (score 5):

Если с задачей загрузки DLL в память вы уже справились, то дело осталось за малым. Предположим, что пример кода, приведенный вами рабочий:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] assemblyBytes = webClient.DownloadData("https://mysite.com");
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
```

И в результате выполнения данного кода мы получили сборку в переменную `assembly`. Теперь, основываясь на знании имени типа и вызываемого метода, можно получить тип и вызвать из него метод следующим образом:

```
// получим тип (мы знаем его имя - myClass)
Type type = assembly.GetType("myClass");
// создадим экземпляр объекта заданного типа
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

// вызовем метод из полученного экземпляра у заданного типа
type.InvokeMember(
  "GetSum", 
  BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, 
  null,
  obj,
  new Object[] {5}
);
```

Чтобы все отработало успешно, нужно учитывать некоторые нюансы. У типа `myClass` либо не должно быть вообще конструкторов, чтобы беспараметрический конструктор по умолчанию за нас создала CLR, либо должен быть один беспараметрический конструктор, чтобы [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx) смог зоздать экземпляр объекта. Также, имена типов должны быть корректны, при несовпадении будет ошибка. Последний параметр у метода [`Type.InvokeMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx) - это массив с аргументами, передаваемыми вызываемому члену (методу).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, ответ помог мне освоить основные принципы.

Answer (score 5):

Если нужная библиотека известна на этапе компиляции - на нее можно сослаться точно так как как и на любую другую. Только не забудьте удалить ее из выходной директории (например, через Post Build Event) когда компилятор ее туда автоматически скопирует. Или, для тех кто знаком с MSBuild, можно поиграться с метаданными Reference.

Чтобы загрузить такую сборку с сервера, вам нужно будет:

1. подписаться на событие `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` и вернуть сборку когда CLR попытается загрузить ее и не найдет;
2. убедиться что ни один из ваших методов, вызываемых до загрузки сборки, не ссылается на классы из той сборки.

Вот так работать не будет:

```
void Foo()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ...;
    myClass.getId(0);
}
```

А вот так - будет:

```
void Foo()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ...;
    Bar();
}

void Bar()
{
    myClass.getId(0);
}
```

Comment: Второй способ может быть нерабочим на моно. Майкрософтный дотнет грузит будто построчно, моно - пофайлово. Плюс минус, глубоко не вникал.